# I Have Edited my Question Can You Please Re-open It?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, reopen-closed

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Send Email with Credential Already Entered in Batch File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65011960/send-email-with-credential-already-entered-in-batch-file)

I have edited my question and I would like my question to be reopened so I can find out the answer I need.

Answer (score 0):

When you edit your question to be fit for reopening, it will advance to the *Reopen Votes* queue, where your question will be reviewed by trusted users. If three users decide that your edit qualifies the post for reopening, then it will be reopened!

If after a few days your question remains closed, that must mean that your edit wasn't enough, that the post still wouldn't qualify.

All in all, a meta post isn't required, and doing so puts you in the risk of the [meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269349/13552470).

Comment: "...that must mean that your edit wasn't enough, that the post still wouldn't qualify...." True, but additionally it could also be that the post did qualify but the reviewer in the reopen queue did overlook it. Errors happen and meta is the place to solve disputes.  What I would have expected is a better explanation why the question is ontopic despite the negative reviews.